# Problema en Form_Tag y recepción de parámetros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buen día, tengo un problema al momento de enviar los parámetros de mi form_tag ya que solo esta enviando una linea (tr) en los parámetros al momento de hacer el submit, ademas me marca un error en los parámetros ya que tengo un modelo de adicionales para los pagos de la semanas.

La definición de mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
      <tbody>
        <%=form_tag(controller: "payrolls", action: "create", method: "post") do%>

          <% @payroll.each do |payroll| %>

            <div style= "display: none"><%= ad = ad(payroll.id) %></div>

            <tr>
              <td><%=hidden_field_tag(:week_id,  payroll.week_id) %></th>
              <td><%=payroll.employee.fullname%><%= hidden_field_tag(:employee_name, payroll.employee.id) %></th>
              <td><%=payroll.department.name%><%=hidden_field_tag(:department_name,  payroll.department.id) %></th>

              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:jueves, payroll.employee_wd.jueves)%></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:viernes, payroll.employee_wd.viernes)%></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:sabado, payroll.employee_wd.sabado) %></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%=text_field_tag(:domingo, payroll.employee_wd.domingo) %></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:lunes,payroll.employee_wd.lunes) %></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:martes, payroll.employee_wd.martes)%></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:miercoles, payroll.employee_wd.miercoles) %></td>
              <th><%= text_field_tag(:dias_trabajados, payroll.dias_trabajados) %></th><!-- Dias Trabajados    -->
              <th><%=text_field_tag(:dias_vacaciones,  payroll.dias_vacaciones) %></th><!-- Dias de Vacaciones    -->
              <td><%=text_field_tag(:faltas,  payroll.faltas) %></th><!-- Faltas    -->
              <th><%= text_field_tag(:total_sueldo_bruto, payroll.total_sueldo_bruto) %></th><!-- total sueldo bruto    -->

              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:bonos,  ad[0]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:fletes,  ad[1])%></td>
              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:jueves,  ad[2] )%></td>
              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:incapacidad,  ad[3]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:finiquito,  ad[4]) %></td>
              <td><%=text_field_tag(:total_percepciones,  payroll.total_percepciones)%></th><!--  Total Percepciones   -->

              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:caja_ahorro,  ad[5]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:prestamo_aporta,  ad[6]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:prestamo,  ad[7] )%></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:comida,  ad[8]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= text_field_tag(:uniforme, ad[9]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= text_field_tag(:pension_alimenticia, ad[10] )%></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= text_field_tag(:infonavit, ad[11]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= text_field_tag(:fonacot, ad[12]) %></td>
              <td><%=text_field_tag(:total_retenciones,  payroll.total_retenciones) %></th><!-- total retenciones   -->

              <td><%=text_field_tag(:sueldo_fiscal,  payroll.sueldo_fiscal) %></th><!-- Sueldo fiscal    -->
              <td><%= text_field_tag(:total_sueldo_neto, payroll.total_sueldo_neto) %></th><!--total sueldo neto   -->
            </tr>

          <% end %>
          <tr>
            <td colspan ='30'></td>
            <td>
              <%= submit_tag("guardar") %>
              <% end %>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
def payroll_params
  params.require(:payroll).permit(:employee_id, :week_id, :department_id, :dias_trabajados, 
  :dias_vacaciones, :faltas, :total_percepciones, :total_retenciones, :total_sueldo_bruto, 
  :total_sueldo_neto, :sueldo_fiscal, :pago_impuesto, :pago_eps, :tipo_pago_fiscal, :tipo_pago_eps, 
  :created_by, :updated_by, employee_wd_attributes: [:jueves, :viernes, :sabado, :domingo, :lunes, :martes, :miercoles])
end
```

Y la definicion de los modelos es la siguiente:

```
class Payroll < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :employee
    belongs_to :department
    belongs_to :week
    has_one    :employee_wd, :dependent=> :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_wd
    belongs_to :employee_cw
    has_many   :employee_wad, :dependent=> :destroy
end

class EmployeeWad < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :payroll
 belongs_to :additional
end

class EmployeeWd < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :payrolls
 belongs_to :construction_works
end
```

Sin embargo :employee_wad se refiere a los campos tales como bono, prestamos, prestamo_aporta,etc pero no se inicializan al crear los pagos de la semana, si no que se crean o actualizan solamente si se utilizan, por tal motivo creo un arreglo sin embargo no se como enviar el arreglo y decirle al controlador como recibirlo.

Adjunto las imagenes de los errores y los parametros enviados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan aconsejarme sobre el error, o bien si no lo estoy haciendo bien o hay una mejor forma todo lo acepto, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar `form_tag` mucha de la "magia" de `form_for` debes hacerla manualmente, esto incluye el `name` de tus campos que defines con los helpers `_tag`. Usando como base lo que pusiste en tu `payroll_params`:

```
def payroll_params
  params.require(:payroll).permit(
    :employee_id, :week_id, :department_id, :dias_trabajados,
    :dias_vacaciones, :faltas, :total_percepciones, :total_retenciones,
    :total_sueldo_bruto, :total_sueldo_neto, :sueldo_fiscal, :pago_impuesto,
    :pago_eps, :tipo_pago_fiscal, :tipo_pago_eps, :created_by, :updated_by,
    employee_wd_attributes: [
      :jueves, :viernes, :sabado, :domingo, :lunes, :martes, :miercoles
    ]
  )
end
```

Ahí especificas que en tus parametros requieres un elemento `payroll` y que éste va a tener como atributos, por ejemplo `employee_id`, entonces para ese campo específico, en vez de definirlo como:

```
hidden_field_tag(:employee_name, payroll.employee.id)
```

, deberías definir el tag como sigue:

```
hidden_field_tag("payroll[][employee_id]", payroll.employee.id)
```

Esto generaría un arreglo para payroll donde vendrían todos tus atributos. Cambié el nombre de `employee_name` a `employee_id`, ya que el nombre del input debe ser el mismo del atributo del modelo.
Sin embargo al momento de actualizar necesitarías saber el id de objeto a actualizar, así que tambien deberías agregar:

```
hidden_field_tag("payroll[][id]", payroll.id)
```

Y luego en tu controlador modificas el payroll_params para que acepte el arreglo:

```
def payroll_params
  params.permit( 
    payroll: [
      :id, :employee_id, :week_id, :department_id, :dias_trabajados,
      :dias_vacaciones, :faltas, :total_percepciones, :total_retenciones,
      :total_sueldo_bruto, :total_sueldo_neto, :sueldo_fiscal, :pago_impuesto,
      :pago_eps, :tipo_pago_fiscal, :tipo_pago_eps, :created_by, :updated_by,
      employee_wd_attributes: [
        :jueves, :viernes, :sabado, :domingo, :lunes, :martes, :miercoles
      ]
    ]
  )
end
```

Y en tu action `update` haces algo como:

```
payroll_params[:payroll].each do |upd_params|
  # Borrar el id, porque en realidad ese campo no lo necesitas para 
  # actualizar, sino solo para traer el registro
  payroll = Payroll.find(upd_params.delete(:id)) 
  # Y actualizas con los strong parameters que definiste en el arreglo
  payroll.update(upd_params)
end
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es maginifica, solo una duda mas con respecto a los adicionales que genero, como puedo hacer para enviar ese parametro? en realidad no lo pude poner como atributo de payrolls ya que no siempre tendra esos valores, ya que solo se insertaran si tienen un valor diferente de 0, pero como no me deja ponerlos en el payroll_params y/o no se como enviarlos.

Comment: No entiendo tu duda. Cualquier asociación extra debes agregarla como `accepts_nested_attributes_for :modelo` en tu modelo, en el controlador la agregas en tu params como `modelo_attributes: [:atributo1, :atributo2]` y en la vista como `payroll[][modelo_attributes][atributo1]` en el name del campo. Si va o no el campo, no debería importar, ya que en tu controlador no está como `require`, sino como `permit`

Comment: Si, hice esa prueba y funciono tal y como mencionas, te agradezco tu ayuda, quedo solucionada mi duda. Muchas gracias